# programmatically change a game center profile photo

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

In the menu of my game, after someone got authenticated with game center I load that persons photo. Obviously they can change that photo from within the game center app but I think it would be much easier for people to have like a small button next to their photo with: "change photo" inside my app.

Is it possible to programmatically change a game center profile photo from within my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now there is no way to change a player's profile picture using the `Game Kit` framework.